# Efficient data structure for a list of index sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to explain by example:

Imagine a list of numbered elements E = [elem0, elem1, elem2, ...].

One index set could now be {42, 66, 128} refering to elements in E. The ordering in this set is not important, so {42, 66, 128} == {66, 128, 42}, but each element is at most once in any given index set (so it is an actual set).

What I want now is a space efficient data structure that gives me another ordered list M that contains index sets that refer to elements in E. Each index set in M will only occur once (so M is a set in this regard) but M must be indexable itself (so M is a List in this sense, whereby the precise index is not important). If necessary, index sets can be forced to all contain the same number of elements.

For example, M could look like:

```
0: {42, 66, 128}
1: {42, 66, 9999}
2: {1, 66, 9999}
```

I could now do the following:

```
for(i in M[2]) { element = E[i]; /* do something with E[1],E[66],and E[9999] */ }
```

You probably see where this is going: You may now have another map M2 that is an ordered list of sets pointing into M which ultimately point to elements in E.

As you can see in this example, index sets can be relatively similar (M[0] and M[1] share the first two entries, M[1] and M[2] share the last two) which makes me think that there must be something more efficient than the naive way of using an array-of-sets. However, I may not be able to come up with a good global ordering of index entries that guarantee good "sharing".

I could think of anything ranging from representing M as a tree (where M's index comes from the depth-first search ordering or something) to hash maps of union-find structures (no idea how that would work though:)

Pointers to any textbook datastructure for something like this are highly welcome (is there anything in the world of databases?) but I also appreciate if you propose a "self-made" solution or only random ideas.

Space efficiency is important for me because E may contain thousands or even few million elements, (some) index sets are potentially large, similarities between at least some index sets should be substantial, and there may be multiple layers of mappings.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Too much information. I unable understand how M generated. Please explain From where taken 1 and 9999 ?

Comment: It's just an example, the numbers are not important. M's entry 2 = {1, 66, 9999} just refers to the elements E[1], E[66], E[9999]. If you need something concrete, think of E containing your 10.000 facebook friends and M[2] contains the index of all the friends who befriended each other in March (0=January, 1=February, 2=March).

Comment: Again not absolutely clear for me. E is friends for specified user or it global list of users? M[X] is "friends who befriended each other in X", please clarify this part better as I not understand why this have duplicates, as I understand it a main problem and required optimeze it. All combinations of these users bifriended or bifriended with specified user?

Answer (score 1):

It will be pretty hard to beat an index. You could save some space by using the right data type (eg in gnu C, *short* if less than 64k elements in E, *int* if < 4G...).

*Besides,*

Since you say the order in E is not important, you could sort E a way it maximizes the consecutive elements to match as much as possible the Ms.

For instance,

```
E: { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 }

0: {1,3,5,7}
1: {1,3,5,8}
2: {3,5,7,8}
```

By re-arranging E

```
E: { 1,3,5,7,8,2,4,6 }
```

and using E indexes, not values, you could define the Ms based on subsets of E, giving indexes

```
0: {0-3}     // E[0]: 1, E[1]: 3, E[2]: 5, E[3]: 7 etc...
1: {0-2,4}
2: {1-3,4}
```

this way

- you use indexes instead of the raw numbers (indexes are usually smaller, no negative..)
- the Ms are made of sub-sets, `0-3` meaning 0,1,2,3,

The difficult part is to make the algorithm to re-arrange E so that you maximize the subsets sizes - minimize the Ms sizes.

*E rearrangement algo suggestion*

- sort all Ms
- process all Ms:

algo to build a map, which gives for an element 'x' its list of neighbors 'y', along with *points*, number of times 'y' is just after 'x'

```
Map map (x,y) -> z
for m in Ms
  for e,f in m // e and f are consecutive elements
    if ( ! map(e,f)) map(e,f) = 1
    else map(e,f)++
  rof
rof
```

Get E rearranged

```
ER = {}                 // E rearranged
Map mas = sort_map(map) // mas(x) -> list(y) where 'y' are sorted desc based on 'z' 
e = get_min_elem(mas)   // init with lowest element (regardless its 'z' scores)


while (mas has elements) 
  ER += e        // add element e to ER
  f = mas(e)[0]  // get most likely neighbor of e (in f), ie first in the list
  if (empty(mas(e))
    e = get_min_elem(mas) // Get next lowest remaining value
  else
    delete mas(e)[0]  // set next e neighbour in line
    e = f
  fi
elihw
```

The algo (map) should be `O(n*m)` space, with n elements in E, m elements in all Ms.

Comment: Good points. Thanks. I like the idea of using index intervals when possible. As you said, the magic then lies in how to rearrange E where I am not sure if that is doable (in a reasonable amount of time). But I will definitely look more into this direction.

Comment: Added a suggested algorithm - hopefully it's clear enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may combine all numbers from M and remove duplicates and name it as UniqueM.

All M[X] collections convert to bit masks. For example int value may store 32 numbers (To support of unlimited count you should store array of ints, if array size is 10 totally we can store 320 different elements). long type may store 64 bits.

```
E: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}

M[0]: {6, 8, 1}
M[1]: {2, 8, 1}
M[2]: {6, 8, 5}
```

Will be converted to:

```
UniqueM: {6, 8, 1, 2, 5}
M[0]: 11100 {this is 7}
M[1]: 01110 {this is 14}
M[2]: 11001 {this is 19}
```

**Note:**
Also you may combine my and ring0 approaches, instead of rearrange E make new UniqueM and use intervals inside it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I like this idea a lot for the cases where not all elements in E appear in M (that is |M| << |E|). Unfortunately, in my case every element in E appears at least once in M and therefore UniqueM becomes the same as E. But this idea may be useful for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Bit arrays may be used. They're arrays of elements `a[i]` which are `1` if `i` is in set and `0` if `i` is not in set. So every set would occupy exactly `size(E)` bits even if it contain a few or no members. Not so space efficient, but if you compress this array with some compression algorithm it will be much less in size (possibly reaching ultimate entropy limit). So you can try dynamic Markov coder or RLE or group Huffman and choose one most efficient for you. Then, iteration process could include on-the-fly decompression followed by linear scanning for `1` bits. For looong `0` runs you could modify decompression algorithm to detect such cases (RLE is simplest case for it).

If you found sets having small defference, you may store sets `A` and `A xor B` anstead of `A` and `B` saving space for common parts. In this case to iterate over `B` you'll have to unpack both `A` and `A xor B` then `xor` them.

Comment: Interesting... I thought of bitsets but not really about compressing them. I will try how well compression works for my specific bit fields and come back to you. Another idea may be to use binary decision diagrams (BDDs) as a form of bit-set compression.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful solution:

```
E: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}

M[0]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 14, 15}
M[1]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 14, 15}
M[2]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13}
```

Cache **frequently used items**:

```
Cache[1] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Cache[2] = {14, 15}
Cache[3] = {-2, 7, 8, 9} //Not used just example.

M[0]: {-1, 10, -2}
M[1]: {-1, 11, -2}
M[2]: {-1, 12, 13}
```

Mark links to cached list as negative numbers.